# qml как получить нужный мне элемент по индексу в ListView?

Tags: qt, qml

Есть ListView с определённым количеством элементов. С помощью count() я могу подсчитать сколько элементов в модели, но как мне обратиться например к 13-му элементу и получить его высоту?  model.get(13).height - не работает.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListView {
        id: list

        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 20
        cacheBuffer:1000
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: dg

            border.color: Qt.darker(color, 1.2)
            color:  "#ccffcc"
            height:  100
            width: parent.width
            Text {
                text: "id: " + model.get(13).height
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }

        footer: Item {
            id: ft

            width: parent.width
            height: 100
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: не совсем понятна поставленная задача, высота элемента в данном случае это высота делегата

Comment: @freakMeduza Да всё верно, это высота текущего делегата, но мне например нужно получить высоту какого то определённого элемента и не обязательно в делегате.

Comment: в delegate: вы описываете представление данных из модели, описание будет актульным для каждого элемента. В вашем случае модель представляет собой intergers as model (https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#qml-data-models), т.е. вы создаете определенное кол-во повторяющихся элементов (делигатов), они все одинаковые.

Comment: Так parent.heigth

Comment: @freakMeduza Вы всё правильно говорите, но мы можем высоту каждого элемента, а так же цвет и т.д. варьировать как хотим, так вот меня интересует тот случай, когда размер элементов разный и я хочу получить размер определённого элемента и вывести его в другом элементе например в 100м элементе, я хочу вывести в тексте размер 13го

Comment: @eri parent.heigth таким образом я получу размер текущего элемента, а мне нужно получить  размер определённого элемента, не зависимо от того в каком элементе отрабатывает делегат

Answer (score 2):

ListView отображает только некоторое количество элементов, необходимых для прокрутки. Нельзя надеяться что элемент 13 будет на экране. В результате выполнения увидите что только 17 отрисовано.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2


Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ListView {
        id: list

        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 20
        cacheBuffer:1000
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: dg

            border.color: Qt.darker(color, 1.2)
            color:  "#ccffcc"
            height:  100
            width: parent.width
            Text {
                text: "view length: " + list.children[0].children.length
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }

        footer: Item {
            id: ft

            width: parent.width
            height: 100
        }
    }
}
```

По идее можно так, но 13 это не индекс модели, а элемент в буфере вывода:

```
list.children[0].children[13].height
```

Попробуйте заменить ListView на Column с Repeater - он отобразит все элементы(не проверял) и тогда достанете через индекс из children.

Попробуйте ещё так, но будут проблемы в том что этот элемент не сужествует, а данные с него уже запросили.

```
id: "child"+model.index
```